# An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details. MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, linq, exception, command, definition

im getting this error

[image]

but I have no idea why its happening. It stops happening when I restart visual studio, but after a while, it happens again. Its weird, since it happens just right after logging in. It makes me think that I left a connection open or there is something else going on. You guys have any idea of what could it be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to tell without knowing your project. But it may have to do with executing code in a setter, which is generally seen as an anti-pattern. (As an aside: the reason for that is that a setter suggests that you only change that little piece of the object's state, without side effects). An improvement would be to loop through `ProjectList` not sooner than when the `ProjectExtensionList` is addressed.

If setting the value for `ProjectList` is part of the materialization of its containing object (`DashboardModel`) the loop may cause a database read that has to wait for a connection that is involved in reading values for `DashboardModel`s. If you defer the looping until when it is really necessary, at that point in time the `DashboardModel` object is in its final state and the connection should be available.

Comment: In other words, I should let the setter to only set the value and find a different way to do the looping or the logic that i'm trying to achieve. I'll try that. If I dont get the error during the whole day, then i guess this should be the answer.